# DIV Tags moving in random directions

Tags: jquery, animation, html

I am trying to make the div tags with different ID to move in random/different directions. How can i achieve that? Below are some of my code. Kindly advise.

I already assign a random coordinates, but it still not working ?

```
function runALl(item) {    
    var coordinates = Math.floor(Math.random()*101+1);
    var cycle1;
    //alert(item);
    (cycle1 = function() {
        var m = randomRange(coordinates,coordinates);
        var n = randomRange(coordinates,coordinates);
        item.animate({left:'+='+n},2000);
        item.animate({left:'+='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000);
        item.animate({left:'-='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000);
        item.animate({left:'-='+n},2000);
        item.animate({top:'-='+n},2000,cycle1)
    })();
}
```

Comment: could you show us what `randomRange` does? :o

Comment: function randomRange(min,max) {
 return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
 }

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to demontrate your code

Comment: @LucasLi If `randomRange` is what you posted in the comment, it will allways return `min`. No random value.

Comment: @Yoshi how can I goes about it ?

Comment: @LucasLi Supply better arguments. You pass the same value for `min` and `max` (`randomRange(coordinates,coordinates);`).

Answer (score 0):

Your `coordinates` variable does not get updated.

You don't move `div` different `id`, item do not change anytime in your function

Based on the fiddle you provided. The moves are done serially, on only one object. Also it moves in 0 - 45 - 90 - 135 ... -directions. Because you don't update the "random" value.

Send in an array of div-elements and iterate through them, providing different random values to each.
Update the random value before each time you should use it, otherwise it will stay the same.

Comment: What do you meant? I cant move div tags with different IDs?

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to target different tags. Based on your code "item" is the only thing that is moved. One thing. you should iterate through an array of "items" and move each of them individually

Comment: Bro need your help. I got an array storing <div id="Predator[randomID]"><img src=""></img></div> and the random id goes 1..2..3..4.. and so on ... But my runALl(item) cant capture them and play and move in random directions.

my code can be found >> jsfiddle.net/Pd435